# Error connecting to SQL Server 2008 with Django

Tags: python, django, sql-server-2008, django-mssql

I am using `django-mssql` and SQL Server 2008, but I found that it always errors when I do some
commands,for example:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

the error is below:

raise OperationalError(e, "Error opening connection: " + connection_string) sqlserver_ado.dbapi.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, '\xb7\xa2\xc9\xfa\ xd2\xe2\xcd\xe2\xa1\xa3', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u"\u7 528\u6237 'sa' \u767b\u5f55\u5931\u8d25\u3002", None, 0, -2147217843), None), 'E rror opening connection: PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=115.238.106.101,60433;Net work Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=rvdb_2;UID=sa;PWD=xxx')

When  I use Microsoft SQL Server Management studio client, I can successfully connect the database.

I got some infomation from：
http://code.google.com/p/django-mssql/issues/detail?id=76
but I still tried I got wrong and I think the solution provided is wrong.

Comment: I reformatted as best I could but it looks like some of your error message got removed somehow, and that's the most important bit to have.  It definitely is a connection error, but I don't know that we have enough information to give a useful response without the full error message.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  However, I  have managed to deduce it this way:  If the SQL Server is on the development machine, it works just fine.  When the SQL Server is on a remote machine, it doesn't work.  Unfortunately, I have still not resolved the issue.  :(

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel DiPaolo 
Thant's the message I copied from consle.
and I am sure that's all....
as I know this is because the  newer mssql2008 is hardcoded..
you can see the url http://code.google.com/p/django-mssql/issues/detail?id=76
 but I can't get it out...I think his code is wrong

Comment: It can't possibly be, part of the traceback is quite obviously cut off:  `ngo.db.backends.sqlserver_ado.dbapi.OperationalError:` should be `django.db.backends.sqlserver_ado.dbapi.OperationalError:` - if you used the Windows console I'm guessing you missed the first three columns of copying.

Comment: this one.....and I have change password


  raise OperationalError(e, "Error opening connection: " + connection_string)
sqlserver_ado.dbapi.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, '\xb7\xa2\xc9\xfa\
xd2\xe2\xcd\xe2\xa1\xa3', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u"\u7
528\u6237 'sa' \u767b\u5f55\u5931\u8d25\u3002", None, 0, -2147217843), None), 'E
rror opening connection: PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=115.238.106.101,60433;Net
work Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=rvdb_2;UID=sa;PWD=xxx')

Comment: this problem is obviously the code error.and I google tell me  the newer mssql2008 is hardcode,can't change it...AND  I use django1.1 to
connect it

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I think the issue is that you don't have the database already created. The mssql backend doesn't seem to do this for you. As soon as I created the database and used the settings below everything worked!

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'provider': 'SQLNCLI10.1',
            'extra_params' : 'DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True'
        },
    }
}
```